# Subdifferential of $\sqrt{a(x)_+^2 + b(x)_+^2}$ where $a,b$ are convex

Tags: convex-analysis, subgradient

Let $a:R^k\to R$ and $b:R^k\to R$ be finite valued convex functions. Let $t_+=\max(0,t)$ be the positive part for any real $t\in R$. Define
$$F(x)=\sqrt{a(x)^2_+ + b(x)^2_+}$$
I am looking for references (or a direct proof) regarding the subdifferential of the convex function $F$
at points $x$ such that $a(x)=0=b(x)$.
The close result that comes to mind is Corollary 16.72 in the book Bauschke and P.L. Combettes: *Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces* and results in that section of the book.

Remark: The subdifferential of the function $(a,b)\mapsto \sqrt{a_+^2+b_+^2}$ at $(0,0)$ is $$S = \{(u,v)\in R_{\ge 0}\times R_{\ge 0} : u^2+v^2\le 1\}.$$

**Questions**:

1. What is the subdifferential of $F$ when $a$ and $b$ are differentialbe at $x$? Is it provably $\cup_{(u,v)\in S} (u\nabla a(x) + v\nabla b(x) )$?
2. What is the subdifferential of $F$ without differentiability of $a,b$? Is it
   always $\cup_{(u,v)\in S} (u\partial a(x) + v\partial b(x))$?

Note that in both cases, the inclusions $u\nabla a(x) + v\nabla b(x)\subset \partial F(x)$
and $u\partial a(x) + v\partial b(x)\subset \partial F(x)$ are straightfoward. The question is whether equality holds.